# Whats the most memory conserving method to create an infinite amount of sliding UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, uicollectionview

I'm creating a project which uses a `UICollectionView`. As the user selects a cell this slides them to another `UICollectionView` of similar nature. Ive been noticing that no matter how I go about this I wind up with mountains of memory usage.

I've been experimenting with placing `UICollectionView`'s in full page `UICollectionViewCell`'s so as to take advantage of the reusability of `UICollectionViews`. The downside of this approach has been memory retention as the CollectionViews are never fully deallocated. Ive also heard that it is not the best practice to put a `UICollectionView` in a `UICollectionView`.

I've experimented with `UIPageViewController`'s containing `UIViewController`'s with the `UICollectionView` inside. This is more efficient as the `UIViewController`'s can be deallocated as the user swipes back however as long as the user continues to select cells and create new view controllers the memory grows unbounded looking like a mountain.

As a bit of a hybrid I attempted as well to put ViewControllers containing `UICollectionView`'s on `UICollectionViewCell`'s. This method seemed to work best but I had to deallocate the view controllers manually as the user swiped.

Are there any strategies or libraries anyone could recommend that would fit this problem. How can I keep the memory down. I understand I'll need some kind of reusable views.

Ive been looking into this Library so far thank you in advance for all of your advise

[Parchment Library](https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're saying. You have a `UICollectionView` that can drill down to another `UICollectionView`, leaving the first one and its backing data retained until you come back and pop it off. Drilling down further and further allocates more and more memory until you back out.

I'd keep things as simple as possible. Solutions like putting a `UICollectionView` inside `UICollectionViewCells` can cause your code to get unnecessarily complicated, resulting in new issues and code that's programmer-hostile. If the user experience that works best is a collection view UI that you can drill down into infinitely, then go with that paradigm.

Your issue is not with `UICollectionViews,` it's in managing your backing data's memory use. That could be done a few ways. It would help to know what kind of data you have that's so large, and what "large" means, but here are a few approaches that come to mind.

One idea would be to unload any large data when you go to the next screen. For example, if your datasource uses an array with a bunch of large images, clear them out when the next view is pushed. Reload the data when your view appears again, or do it lazily when the view's cells need it, whichever works best for you. This would be the easiest approach and probably take care of your memory concerns.

A second approach would be to use one `UICollectionView` and use custom animations so it looks like a new collection view is pushing/popping from an old one, when in fact you're just changing the data for the collection view and reloading. You could even provide animations that are more interesting than pushing/popping.

On top of either of these approaches, you could implement the `UICollectionView` prefetch API calls to load data just before you need it. That will reduce your memory footprint even further.

All of these approaches assume that you can load the data to display from storage-- that it's not just in memory from recent webservice requests. Your users are guaranteed a miserable experience if your app has to keep requesting the same large data from the web over and over. So, if you don't have the data stored locally already, set up a cache.

Regardless of the approach, this is something you should be able to handle without adopting a library. `UICollectionViews` are designed to be memory friendly. Your issue is really in determining the best way to manage your backing data's memory use.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and for writing such a detailed answer. Do you believe that a pageViewController would be the best approach then for managing the deallocation of the data source as the user swipes or would perhaps a viewcontroller on a collection view cell being the nest view controller approach is a bit complicated. Currently the data is mostly images which are cached using SD_WebImage.

Comment: You don't need to deallocate the datasource, you just need to deallocate the data that the datasource uses when you don't need that, and then load it before you need it again, or on demand. Since it sounds like you're showing one image on screen at a time, a pageviewcontroller probably does make more sense than a collectionview, but that's because of the user experience, not because a pageviewcontroller is better at managing memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response, on each page I am trying to put a grid of pictures in a collectionView I apologize for the confusion. As the user taps on one of the pictures it slides to the next page with another grid of pictures with the same functionality enabled and so on and so forth. Would you still recommend the pageViewController over the full page sized CollectionViewCell?

Comment: Use a collectionview for the grid. Where would the "full page sized CollectionViewCell" appear?

Comment: The full sized collectionview cell would house the grid collectionview on it there would be 2 collection views in this model